# Creating buttons in android splashscreen to move to next location

Tags: android

I have created a splash screen in which i want to create two buttons PLAY and INFO.I want that when i click INFO it will go to the next splashscreen that is of Instruction Manual  and also want that these two buttons should not be visible on splashscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ViewFlipper for this.

```
<ViewFlipper ...>
<LinearLayout>(your buttons)</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>(info page)</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>(the actual game)</LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

and then in your code use ViewFlipper's `setDisplayedChild(int index)` method to change the visible LinearLayout.